# ClientState is missing from header in a resource notification

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications, webhooks

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks) example to subscribe to Resource and Lifecycle notifications on a document library. It is working well and I am receiving notifications but, for some reason, the ClientState is not in the headers.
Here is an image of the response in ngrok:
[image: Screenshot of ngrok response]
I can see the clientstate in the response but not in the header. Was there some change that I am not aware of and now we are supposed to get the clientstate from the response instead of the header?